# How to adjust the x axis in seaborn.regplot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I need help to adjust the x axis to 300. I am using `sns.regplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

dataset = pd.read_csv('ocv.csv')

sns.regplot(data=dataset, x='gdl', y='sales')
sns.regplot(data=dataset, x='lft', y='sales')
sns.regplot(data=dataset, x='newspaper', y='sales')
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can control the limits of X and Y axis of your plots using matplotlib function `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()`.

You just need to add `plt.xlim(0,300)` to your code.